# Polynomial breakdown

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

> $p(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{k}z^{k} \in C[x]$ with polynomial degree $n \geq 1$
>
> $z_{1}, z_{2}, ..., z_{n}$ is l-times zero (point)
>
> You have to show with complete induction the following identities:
>
> $a_{0} = (-1)^{n} a_{n}*\prod_{k=1}^{n} z_{k}$ and $ a_{n-1} = -a_{n}*\sum_{k=1}^{n} z_{k} $

*My start looks like this:*

I reshaped the statement to:
If p(x) = $a* \prod_{k=1}^{n} (x-z_{k}) = \sum_{n}^{n} a_{k}x^{k} $  then:

$a_{n} = a, a_{0} = (-1)^{n} * a * \prod_{k=1}^{n} z_{k}$ and $a_{n-1} = -a \sum_{k=1}^{1} z_{k}$

Induction start with: n = 1

$p(x) = a* \sum_{k=1}^{1} (x-z_{k})$ = a*($x-z_{1}$ = $ax - az_{1}$ = $\sum_{k=0}^{1} a_{k}x^{k} = a_{1}x + a_{0}$

So: $a_{n} = a, a_{0} = (-1)^{n}*a*\prod_{k=1}^{1}z_{k}$
$ -a_{1}z_{1} = -a \sum_{k=1}^{1} z_{k}$

Induction start:
$ p´(x) = a*\prod_{k=1}^{n+1} (x-z_{k}) ) \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} a´_{k}x^{k} $

So i  have to show:

$ a´_{n+1} = a$ ,

$ a´_{0}=(-1)^{n+1} * a * \prod_{k=0}^{n+1}$,

$ a´_{n} = -a * \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} z_{k}$

Im not sure about this and i dont get it completly.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please complete your question.

Comment: Now its completed